# Data Binding API How to set a String

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

When I use `Data Binding API` in android I want to remove boilerplate code like `findViewById`.

However I have a simple login_fragment which takes a `user-name` and a `user-pw`. After clicking on `Sign Up` it should get the corresponding strings and write it into my `User-Class`:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private String user;
    private String pw;

    public User() {}

    @Bindable
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getPw() {
        return pw;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.myuser.lala.BR.user);
    }

    public void setPw(String pw) {
        this.pw = pw;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.myuser.lala.BR.pw);
    }
}
```

My XML-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data class="LoginData">
        <variable
            name="logindata"
            type="com.example.myname.lala.User" />
    </data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/textview_user" />

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/enter_name"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="@{logindata.user}"
        style="@style/edittext_user" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/textview_pw" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:text="@{logindata.pw}"
        style="@style/edittext_pw" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/login_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I am binding the variable in my `xml-layout` to the UI with:

```
LoginData logindata = DataBindingUtil.bind(getView());
logindata.setLogindata(new User());
```

and then after I typed a user-name and password I click on sign-up and I was hoping that Data Binding automatically updates `user` and `pw` in `User-Class` via `setUser` and `setPw` but when I try to retrieve user or pw over:

```
Log.e("user","" + logindata.getLogindata.getUser()); //output: user null
Log.e("pw","" + logindata.getLogindata.getPw()); //ditto
```

Maybe I misunderstand the purpose of a `ViewModel` like my `User-Class`...

Answer (score 0):

Today binding in Android is 'one way'. If you need values of EditText use watcher.

Add `app:addTextChangedListener` attribute

```
        <EditText
            ....
            android:text="@{viewModel.loginText}"
            app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.loginWatcher}" />
```

and corresponding getter for watcher:

```
public TextWatcher getLoginWatcher() {
    return new SimpleTextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            loginText = charSequence.toString();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you tse.. but I always get `data binding error - could not find accessor com.example.user.lala.User.loginwatcher` in my login.xml? Do you have an idea?

Comment: could you show the definition of watcher and part of xml with view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Two-way DataBinding inorder to get values back from view/control. Simple provide `=` sign after `@` to implement Two-way binding

```
android:text="@={logindata.user}"
```